# Connect Laravel Application to Joomla

Tags: php, laravel, joomla

I'm trying to connect my Laravel application to my Joomla 3 instance on the same server. I have an ajax call within Laravel that is POSTing to a Laravel Controller file (PHP), but I am getting the error:

**Class 'App\Http\Controllers\JFactory' not found in ../public_html/webapp/app/Http/Controllers/JoomlaController.php:12**

I think there's something simple I'm missing.

The ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ url() }}/settings/save', 
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'text', 
        data: "test",
        success: function(data) {
                console.log("posted: " + data);
        },
        error: function(){
                console.log("failure posting settings");
        }
 });
```

and I have the above url routed to JoomlaController.php, which is like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .'/../../../../' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');


class JoomlaController extends Controller {



public function saveSettings(Request $settings) {

    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $field = $db->quoteName('value') . ' = ' . $db->quote($settings);
    $condition = $db->quoteName('item_id') . ' = ' . $user->get('id');
    $table = $db->quoteName('nicqb_fields_values');
    $columns = array('field_id','item_id', 'value');
    $values = array('1', $user->get('id'), '\''.$settings.'\'');

        $query
            ->insert($table)
            ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
            ->values(implode(',', $values));
    }

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result = $db->execute();

}

}

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Joomla questions are always on-topic at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  FYI, `$field` and `$condition` are unused variables and the third param should be quoted using `quote()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if the problem is with Joomla or Laravel, so I decided to post here hoping to cast a wider net.

Comment: I fully understand, I just wanted to extend the invitation -- some people don't even know that JSE exists.